# Is public search form vulnerable to DDOS attack?

Tags: ddos

I have a typical search form as one of the main functions. As it is a public one, I am scared of getting DDOS attacked.

The only way I think of to avoid it is to:

1. I will use a `method="post"` `form` with `token` on it.
2. When the user/attacker submit the `form`.
3. I will check if the button is clicked and if the `token` is correct.
4. If both true, I will reload the page along with the search value. ex `www.url.com/?q=search_value`

Will this prevent the DDOS attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No. Why should it? Even if you just have a static single page site, you are susceptible to DDOS attacks that might consist of nothing more then repeated requests for that single page ...

Comment: I see. Thank you. Do you have any recommendations on what I can do against it?